# Precise meaning of "accompany"

Tags: vocabulary

If I were to say "X is accompanied by Y", would it mean that (i) "Y takes place at the same time as X", or that (ii) "Y takes places after X"?

I have found definitions (i) and (ii) in dictionaries, so I am a bit confused... For example, Collins says: "If one thing accompanies another, it happens or exists at the same time, or as a result of it."

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/accompany

P.S.: There is a similar thread on this which supports definition (i), but I am still hesitant because of dictionary definitions.

[Meaning of "A accompanies B"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/275574/meaning-of-a-accompanies-b)

If there truly is an ambiguity of meaning, should I avoid using "accompany" in scientific discussions where distinction between concurrency and sequentiality matters?

Thank you.

Comment: It depends what X and Y are. The normal meaning is that both things happen together, but if Y is obviously the result of X (and happens immediately after it), your definition (ii) is possible (as in the Collins example of applause 'accompanying' the winning of a vote.

Comment: How about when the nature of X and Y makes both (i) and (ii) possible?

Comment: To enable me to answer that you would have to tell me what they are!

Comment: It could mean either. The possible ambiguity you noticed in the definition is usually resolved by the context. "To accompany" simply means "to be in company with". The context will then have to define what "company" is and what "to be in one" means. When you say "X is accompanied by Y", you put stress on "X", and make it look original, more important. Thus, without any context, it indeed looks as if Y joined X's company and went along or followed.

Comment: If you're writing a scientific paper you should indicate if there is a causal relationship between X and Y, if they have a common cause, if they occur together by chance, or if you are unsure. Saying "X accompanies Y" is too vague - consider e.g. that smoking causes lung cancer, but coughing (which often follows smoking) does not cause lung cancer, and nor does using a cigarette lighter.

Answer (score 0):

The root of “accompany” is an Old French word meaning “to take as a companion.”

https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=accompany&ref=searchbar_searchhint

Its modern English meaning is “experience as a pair.” Because what we mean as cause and effect is “wonted succession in time,” the word “accompany” may denote either simultaneity or else succession.

To be precise, I would recommend

> A precedes B

or

> A is simultaneous with B

to distinguish between the two possibile meanings of “accompany.”